# SourceTree: CryptographicException when try to register Host-Accounts

Tags: version-control, windows-10, password-encryption, sourcetree

Im using SourceTree in the actual version (1.7.0.32509).

I got a notebook(before win8.1) and a Desktop(before win7) with it and upgraded both devices to win10.

When i want to register Host-Accounts for my repositories it works fine on the notebook, but with the excaxt same configuration (directories, installation, etc) it fails me on my desktop which reports a 
System.Security.CryptographcException:AccessDenied
when attempting to store a password.

Seems there is no solution to this on the net which works for me atm.

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new windows user and setup all from scratch.

This was the only solution at sourcetree forums as well.